# Sur l’utilisation de « laquelle »

Tags: pronoms

なぜlaquelle を使ってるのでしょうか？
qui で繋いでもいいのでは？

Pourquoi l’auteur utilise « laquelle » là-bas ?

Le déploiement de ces soldats a été immédiatement dénoncé par la présidence ukrainienne, laquelle le considère comme un moyen de « pression psychologique » employé par le Kremlin, qui a massé, depuis novembre, plus de 100 000 soldats aux frontières orientales de l’Ukraine.

Comment: Que signifie la phrase au début de la question ?

Comment: @Toto Google translate donne quelque chose de compréhensible à partir du japonais : *Why are you using laquelle? Is it okay to connect with qui?* / *Pourquoi utilisez-vous laquelle ? Est-il acceptable de se connecter avec qui ?*

Comment: @jlliagre: Merci

Answer (score 1):

Dans cette phrase, laquelle est un pronom relatif qui reprend « la présidente ukrainienne ». Il s’agit du langage soutenu. En langage courant on pourrait utiliser le pronom relatif « qui » ou faire une autre phrase commençant « elle ».

Comment: Je pense qu'ici, ils ont utilisé *laquelle* justement pour éviter la répétition avec le *qui* un peu plus loin. La formulation *"[...] par la présidence ukrainienne, **qui** le considère comme un moyen de « pression psychologique » employé par le Kremlin, **qui** a massé, depuis novembre [...]"* n'est pas très digeste.